# Scala, covariant type definition

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, variance

I have a set of classes inheriting from `Step[I, O]` where `I` is the input and `O` the output. I would like to define a more specific subclass that don't care about the `I`.

Here a my definitions :

```
trait Step[I, O] {
  def apply(c:Context, i:I):Either[Error, O]
}

// H : Action handler
// A : Action handled by H
// R : Result of successful A
class Legacy[H, A <: Action[H], R](action: A with Result[R], handler: H) extends Step[Any, R] {
  override def apply(c:Context, a: Any): Either[Error, R] = {
    handler.run(action)
  }
}
```

But those *steps* are chained trough a DSL that use the output `O` of a step as the input `I` of the next one.

```
// DSL excerpt
class AndThenBuilder[I] {
  def andThen[O](producer: (Context, I) => Step[I, O]) = ???
}

//...
val intToString:Step[Int, String] = //new SubType of Step
val legacy:Step[Any, String] = // new Legacy( action with Result[String])

//...
execute(intToString) // return AndThenBuilder[String]
 .andThen((_:Context, s:String)=>legacy)
```

The last line, does not compile because the DSL verify the type:

> Required : (Context, String) => Step[String, NotInferedO]
>
> Found :    (Context, String) => Step[Any, String]

I guess that changing `Step[I, O]` to `Step[I_Or_Subtypes, O]` would solve my issue. But I cannot find the syntax to define it in `Step` or `Legacy`, each attempt give me a more cryptic message.

Can someone help me to change my code so that `Step[Any, String]` will be accepted as a `Step[String, String]`. (I can change `Any` by other types) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so that `Step[Any, String]` will be accepted as a `Step[String, String]`

This needs the first parameter to be *contra*-variant, not covariant as in your title. And the syntax is

```
trait Step[-I, O] { ... }
```

And as it happens, `I` *can* be contravariant, but not covariant, because it's used as a method argument type. While `O` can be covariant, but can't be contravariant.

Comment: Yes, indeed using a _contravariant_ solved my issue. I was misunderstanding and mixing both. Thanks.